# XAML: Accessing arbitrary objects in Application's ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, code-behind, resourcedictionary

being a XAML/WPF newbie, I tried to put an arbitrary (i.e. non-WPF) object into my applications resources like

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:a="clr-namespace:MyApp"
         >
  <Application.Resources>
    <a:MyClass x:Key="Model"/>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and access it from my code-behind file using

```
public partial class App : Application
{
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
    base.OnStartup(e);
    var obj = (MyClass)this.FindResource("Model");
    obj.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

`FindResource` got me a `ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException`. I'd be very grateful if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: The code looks fine, is this a complete example?

Comment: Your code as it is works fine on my machine. Make sure you're not mispelling the resource name in your actual code

Comment: It seems that overriding `OnStartup` is *not* the same as binding to the  `Startup` event. See my response below...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it seems that the Resource dictionary is not (yet?) initialized in the overridden `OnStartup` method but available in an `Startup` event handler.

When I use the `Startup` *event*  instead of overriding `OnStartup` like:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:a="clr-namespace:MyApp"
     Startup="Application_Startup"
         >
```

and

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {
```

everything worked fine!